# Jquery textarea get last value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use my  program `<textarea>`
And every time a user enters a new value, it always gives me the first value.
But I always want the last amount
this is my code:

```
<textarea id='txtBackStatus' rows='5' cols='34' onClick = "Message()">

<script>
function Message(){
var result= $('#txtBackStatus').val();
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have multiple textarea elements in the DOM with the same id? If so, that's the problem.

Comment: You need to add an event listener for the input on that textarea element. If you will be using jQuery, it's the `.change()` method

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan 
No only one

Comment: A textarea contains only a single value. Can you please elaborate what you mean with "_last value_" and "_first value_"? Also, `onclick` is not suitable to detect a changed value of a textarea, it gives you just the value of the textarea at the time the element is clicked. Maybe you'd need `onchange` event instead ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an 'onChange' function instead of 'onClick'

Delete the 'onClick' attribute and then try this below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#txtBackStatus").on('change', function() {
   var result = $('#txtBackStatus').val();
   console.log(result);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `.change()` method to get the latest value

```
$( "#txtBackStatus" ).change(function() {
  var result = $('#txtBackStatus').val();
});
```

For more information refer [here](https://api.jquery.com/change/).

Please also note that this event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>` elements.